# How to enable a textbox and wait for criteria to be entered before delete operation in WPF

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am having trouble with deleting a record from my programme. I have a textbox which is disabled by default by the ReadOnly property which is bound to a boolean property of my ViewModel. The textbox permits the user to enter the ID as criteria for the record to be deleted. I have the delete code in my viewmodel, the code suppose to enable the textbox when the delete button is clicked the first time and wait for the user to enter the ID in the textbox and click the delete button the second time to carry out the delete operation. But instead, the code is not working as intended, the code enables the textbox and also run the delete operation without the user entering the ID when the delete button is clicked. Summary of the problem is that the entire delete code block runs when the user click the delete button without even allowing the user to enter the ID of the record to be deleted. Please how can I make the code to enable the textbox for ID an wait for the user to enter the ID and click the delete button the second time for the delete operation to occur?
This is the code:

```
        private RelayCommand deleteCommand;

    public RelayCommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get { return deleteCommand; }
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this record?", "Delete Operation", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question,MessageBoxResult.No);
        if(result == MessageBoxResult.No)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                IDEnabled = false;

                var IsDeleted = ObjStudentService.Delete(NewStudent.Id);
                if (!IsDeleted)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Student Record Deleted", "Delete Operation", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                    LoadData();
                    NewStudent.Id = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to Delete Record, ensure you enter the correct ID.", "Delete Operation", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception Found", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }

        }

    }
```

The "IDEnabled" is the property that disables the ReadOnly property of the ID textbox field so that the user can enter the ID for a particular record to be deleted.

I call the code in the constructor as follows:

```
        public StudentViewModel()
    {
        ObjStudentService = new StudentService();
        LoadData();
        NewStudent = new Student();
     deleteCommand = new RelayCommand(Delete);}
```

This is my binding in the XAML for the delete button:

```
                        <Button x:Name="BtnDelete" Margin="10 0 0 0" IsTabStop="False"
                            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ButtonEnabled}"
                        Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedAccentButton}"
                        ToolTip="Delete record"
                            Command="{Binding Path=DeleteCommand}"
                        Width="75">
                        Delete
                    </Button>
```

Someone please help me look at my code to see where I go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could detect when the textbox is enabled or not when the user clicks the delete button.  If the textbox is disabled, enable it so that the user can type in the ID.  If the textbox is already enabled, validate the input, disable the textbox, and start the delete operation.

```
public void Delete()
{
    if (!IDEnabled) //assuming that if true, the textbox is no longer ReadOnly 
    { 
        IDEnabled = true; //enable the textbox
    } 
    else 
    {
        //validate the ID
        IDEnabled = false; //disable the textbox
        //delete the record
        var IsDeleted = ObjStudentService.Delete(NewStudent.Id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still trying to get to understand your code.

Comment: The first time the button is clicked, the textbox is disabled (`IDEnabled = false`), so you enable it to allow users to type.  The second time the button is clicked, the textbox has been enabled already, so you validate the textbox's input, delete the record and disable the textbox. By disabling the textbox everything is reset.

Comment: What if he condition in the "if" block evaluates o true, that means no delete operation in the "else" block will occur.

Comment: @DaPlug Yes. That would solve your problem, which was that "the entire delete code block runs when the user click the delete button without even allowing the user to enter the ID of the record to be deleted.". The "if" block will toggle the IDEnabled flag, so that the next time that the button is pressed, the "else" block will evaluate to true.

Comment: Thanks so much, it's working just perfectly.